# Loading images when checking their existence with jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, currying

I have this function that is supposed to check for the existence of images up to the point where they stop appearing, based on their title:

```
function LoadPictures(){
        const PIC_MAX = 12;

        var i = 1;

        while (i <= PIC_MAX){
            $.ajax({url: "pic" + i + ".jpg",
                type: "HEAD",
                success: function(){
                    $("body").append("<img src='pic" + i + ".jpg' />");
                },
                error: function(){
                    i = PIC_MAX + 1;
                }
            });

            i++;
        }
    }
```

And yet, when I run the function, all I get are blank boxes. I know the loop correctly counted the existing images based on the amount of boxes appearing, but it failed to load them. Why is that?

Comment: Have you inspected the markup generated by this script?

Answer (score 5):

It's because the callback is asynchronous, so the value of `i` will likely be the last value in the loop every time the callback executes.  Consider the following example ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xef5a/)):

```
var length = 10;
var url = window.location;
for (i=0 ; i<length ; i++) {
    $.get(url, function(result) {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Here, the value logged for `i` will not be 1 through 10, because `i` is a local variable that continues to get updated while the server sends a response.

---

You can use a technique called "currying" to get around this.  Wrap your callback function in another function, which passes in the current value of `i` immediately ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xef5a/3/)):

```
success: (function(i){
    return function() {
        $("body").append("<img src='pic" + i + ".jpg' />");
    }
})(i),
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. It's a rather odd piece of code for me. So, I never would have figured it out. Thanks for the tip.